# Angular UI Grid Scroll Error

Tags: google-chrome, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am using ui grid 3.0.6. Until yesterday it was working fine. But there is a problem in Google chrome now.(Version 56.0.2924.87)

When I scroll the grid, or click on scroll down arrow it starts scrolling very fast. Couldn't control the speed. It was working fine and only in Chrome.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I have several users reporting the same problem here too. I am hoping it has been recognised as a Chrome bug and will be fixed, because otherwise we will have to downgrade or scramble to adapt the angular-ui-grid to cope with this new behaviour.

Comment: Had this same problem. Updating ui-grid (4.0.2) cleared it up for us.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Updating ui-grid to 4.0.2 and angularjs 1.5.0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 30):

Adding this style to my style.css is helped

```
.ui-grid-viewport {
    overflow-anchor: none;
}
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted. Added to project and no longer have problem with fast scrolling to bottom.

Chrome 57
Angular-Ui-Grid @ 3.1.1

Answer (score 19):

It's may be related to "Scroll Anchoring" feature, that has been enabled by default in Chrome 56. 
[description of feature](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5700102471548928)

css-property "overflow-anchor: none", should solve this problem.