# UI GRID insanely fast vertical scroll issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I used UI Grid in my project and below is a snapshot of the `gridOptions` variable that I used. The Problem is everything was working fine. But from past 1 or 2 weeks the vertical scroll is insanely scrolling on just a single scroll. Since `multiSelect` is set to true the clients are unable to check/select specific records the scrollbar scrolls insanely (this happens when user scrolls just once) and the scrollbar reaches to the bottom of the table.

Version :  **ui-grid - v3.2.1**

```
this.gridOptions = {
      appScopeProvider: this,
      infiniteScrollRowsFromEnd: 20,
      enableSelectAll: true,
      multiSelect: true,
      enableColumnResizing: true,
      saveScroll: false,
      saveFocus: false,
      saveGrouping: false,
      enableFiltering: true,
      saveGroupingExpandedStates: false,
      saveTreeView: false,
      infiniteScrollDown: true,
      useExternalFiltering: false,
      useExternalSorting: false,
      enableCellEditOnFocus: false,
      enableCellEdit: false,
      enableRowSelection: true,
      enableFullRowSelection: true,
      enableGridMenu: true,
      enableSorting: true,
      exporterCsvFilename: 'ClientResults.csv',
      exporterCsvLinkElement: angular

      //sorry cant share other code
```

Can anyone help whats wrong.

PS: There are total 2000+ records in the table. Also this happens only in chrome and behaves normal in Firefox.

Comment: So what's exactly is the problem? Can you please make it more clear... Are you able to scroll down or  the scroll is getting disabled in the container which prevents you from selecting the specific records?

Comment: When the user scrolls vertically the grid starts scrolling very fast even if the user scrolled just once and the scrollbar reaches the bottom of the table. This does not allows the user to select or view the in between records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular UI Grid Scroll Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100246/angular-ui-grid-scroll-error)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Got the issue.

The issue was with the version of Chrome 56. Also my ui-grid version was 3.2.0 which I upgraded to 4.0.2 which ultimately solved the issue. This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100246/angular-ui-grid-scroll-error) helped.

Answer (score 22):

For anyone wondering how to solve this without upgrading ui-grid, this fixed my issue on `ui-grid 3.1.1`:

**Add this to your css:**

```
.ui-grid-viewport {
    overflow-anchor: none;
}
```

<sub>[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42297345/1152809)</sub>